# CORS error in downloading with ionic3 file transfer

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using file transfer plugin but anytime I trigger the download I got **cors error** and I have settled every cors error in my backend.

To be sure of this I copied an image url online and I tried downloading the image but I still getting cors error which means its a problem from `ionic` not my backend.

And also I would like to ask that **how do you test the file transfer?** because I run the command

`ionic cordova run browser`

to be able to test the plugin but i am not sure thats the right way maybe thats why I am having the cors issue…

Please help me.

Comment: Please post some request details, especially the http headers.

Comment: You can use this plugin to resolve the CORS error.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: This is the code that will trigger my dowload                    downloadPq(){
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let url="http://www.redwoodsoft.com/dru/museum/gfx/gff/sample/images/png/basi0g01.png";
    fileTransfer.download(url,this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.jpeg').then((entry) =>{
      console.log(entry);
    },(error) =>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

Comment: ohk thanks no more cors error now but i am still getting error code 1  like this        FileTransferError {code: 1, source: "http://www.redwoodsoft.com/dru/museum/gfx/gff/sample/images/png/basi0g01.png", target: "filesystem:file:///persistent/file.jpeg", http_status: null, body: null…}

Comment: Edit your question with some of your code please.

Comment: This are my codes  **downloadPq(){ const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create(); let url="redwoodsoft.com/dru/museum/gfx/gff/sample/images/png/…;; fileTransfer.download(url,this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.jpeg').then((entry) =>{ console.log(entry); },(error) =>{ console.log(error); }); }**

Comment: I served my app today and i try to trigger the download again and now i am getting cors error again please i need a permanent solution to this

Comment: If i dont get cors error now i will get a FileTransferError with CODE 1